# How to do Vlookup across different sheets and fill it down to the last data

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry, i cant screenshot the excel sheet cuz its the company confidential information. Let me try to explain it better.

In column B7(and all the way down), I have some cost centre codes. In column D7, It is where I will need to do a vlookup to find which Department does this cost code belongs to.

For eg, In cell B7 I can have the code:110-120. So in D7 I want to display the name of the department To which the code belongs to.

I have named given the vlookup table a name by adding it in the name manager. It is called:Department_mapping. It is located on another sheet called 'VLOOKUP Table'.

For the department_mapping table,A1 is labelled Cost Centre and A2 is labelled Department. Thus what I need the code to do is to do a vlookup to find which department a particular cost code belongs to and fill it in starting from D7. Also,I need the code to do so till the very last code in column B7.

My exisiting code that I have tried so far is:
On Error Resume Next
Dim MyStringVar1 As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    MyStringVar1 = Application.VLookup(Range("B7"), _
      Worksheets("VLOOKUP Table").Range("A:B"), 2, True)
    On Error GoTo 0
  Range("D7") = MyStringVar1

I need the code to fill not just D7 but the rest of fields down the column. I need the code to autofill the rest too.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? Then I might be able to help you

Comment: I have tried to re-explain the problem. Do take a look to see if you can help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: So let me get this straight. In the department_mapping table, A1 is labelled Cost Centre and A2 is labelled Department. Does that mean that B1 is labelled Cost Centre and B2 is labelled Department as well?

Comment: Hi, My vlookup is fine for D7 already, using the above code. I just need help for the code to help me fill all the way down to the last value.

Comment: You are right about A1 and A2. However, For B1 it has the value(e.g. 106) while B2 has the value: Finance

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand and you need to populated with `VLOOKUP` all cells in column "D" down to the row which has data in column "B" then change your

`selection.value`

to

`sheets("YourSheet").range("D6:D" & Sheets("YourSheet").range("B" & rows.Count).end(xlup).row).value`

this will check the last row with data in column "B" and populate values in column "D" from "D6" all the way to the last row.

Comment: I still get a run-time error 1004 saying: unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: My exisiting code so far after changing to what u suggested is: Sheets("Detail by cc").Range("D7:D" & Sheets("Detail by cc").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value=Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"),[Department_mapping],2,FALSE)

Comment: @jlyh11 most likely you have some look up values that are "#N/A", change  `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to `Application.VLookup` and this should solve it

Comment: sorry, that worked but not the way I wanted. Every single cell displayed #N/A even though there were values that matched

Comment: how can I solve the prob of the code doing vlookup wrongly? Everything displays as NA even though there were departments who matched with a particular cost centre

Comment: ok, try to replace your `VLOOKUP` with the following two lines, i have just checked, they are working for me fine even if there are some #N/A in results: 1st line - `LastRow = Sheets("Detail by cc").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and 2nd line - `Sheets("Detail by cc").Range("D7:D" & LastRow).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7:B" & LastRow), Worksheets("VLOOKUP Table").Range("A:B"), 2, False)`